# Accessing github from static webpage

Tags: javascript, github-api

I'm trying to write a static web page that will pull all the current pull requests in a github repo and display them. I would like to use [octokit.js](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js) But that's for node.js. Is there a straightforward way to make authenticated calls to a github repo form a static webpage?

Comment: there is also a **Browser** section

Comment: but no documentation on formats. I don't know node.js syntax. there's only the one call they have written out that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub's API is very open. You can just `fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/pulls')`. https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests

Do note that there is a limit on un-authenticated requests, but you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Run the example below to see a list of current pull requests against Node.js core.

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/nodejs/node/pulls')
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((pulls) => {
    pulls
      .map((p) => `[${p.number}] ${p.title} (${p.html_url})`)
      .forEach((s) => console.log(s));
  });
```

Comment: So I can run the snippet you gave me but when I run it on my enterprise github server I get an error that led me to put the fetch in "no-cors" more: fetch('https://github.myCompany.com/repos/myUser/repo/pulls', { mode: "no-cors" }) and I get a unexpected end of input. Is there something I'm missing there?

Comment: @MaxMullin I don't have access to GitHub enterprise or know anything about the API it exposes. You should edit your question to include that.